# C++ and undefined reference to XML_Parser

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, g++

i have the following problem, i need use expat.h library, i include the library normally:

```
#include <expat.h>
```

But when i try to create a object

```
XML_Parser Parser = XML_ParserCreate(NULL);
```

Eclipse keppler return **undefined reference to XML_ParserCreate** . I check the library and is included.
I work with ubuntu 13.04 and g++ compiler.

any idea?

Comment: Show the various build commands started by Eclipse, in particular the final link command. I suspect it is lacking `-lexpat`

Answer (score 3):

Probably you didn't link with the library. You should add this `-lexpat` to the compiler`s command line. For example:

```
g++ main.cc -lexpat -o exe
```

A more advanced (and more easy to use, when you get up to speed) option would be to use `pkg-config` as e.g. `$(pkg-config --libs expat)`.

Comment: i add -lexpat and -MMto the compliler`s command line, the error with library expat.h disapear, but return this: `Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++  -o "dash"  ./src/Common/Trace.o  ./src/Alphabet/AlphIO.o ./src/Alphabet/Alphabet.o ./src/Alphabet/AlphabetMap.o  ./src/BigramLanguageModel.o ./src/LanguageModel.o ./src/TrainingHelper.o ./src/das.o  ./main.o   
./src/Common/Trace.o: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [dash] Error 1`

Comment: @jtula different error, and likely a different question-and-answer.

Comment: Is true, sorry. Thanks for the answers.